# How do I search for specific images the fastest in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to know how to find specific images in Python the quickest using mss, Pillow, etc. I only need to be able to input the file path and search a region of the screen for said image.

I've tried mss, but I couldn't find any results. I tried pyautogui, but that was really slow.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to find a specific image on your screen, you can combine the `mss` library for fast screenshots with the `OpenCV` library for image matching. `mss` is indeed faster than many other screen capture methods in Python because it uses native methods for capturing the screen.

Use the following Python code to capture the screen and search for the image:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import mss
from PIL import Image

def find_image_on_screen(image_path, region=None):
    # Load the image you want to find
    needle_img = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    needle_w = needle_img.shape[1]
    needle_h = needle_img.shape[0]

    # Define the screen region to capture
    # region should be a tuple like (left, top, width, height)
    if region is not None:
        monitor = {"top": region[1], "left": region[0], "width": region[2], "height": region[3]}
    else:
        monitor = {"top": 0, "left": 0, "width": needle_w, "height": needle_h}

    with mss.mss() as sct:
        # Capture the screen
        sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)
        # Convert to a numpy array
        screen_img = np.array(sct_img)

        # Convert to a format OpenCV understands
        # PIL images use RGB, but OpenCV uses BGR, so we need to convert
        screen_img_bgr = cv2.cvtColor(screen_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Match the needle image in the haystack (the screen capture)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(screen_img_bgr, needle_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

        # Get the best match position
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        if max_val > 0.8: # set a threshold for matching
            return max_loc
        else:
            return None

# Usage example:
image_path = 'path/to/your/image.png'  # Replace with your image path
region = (0, 0, 800, 600)  # Define the region of the screen you want to search

match_position = find_image_on_screen(image_path, region)
if match_position:
    print(f"Image found at position: {match_position}")
else:
    print("Image not found.")
```

This script loads the image you want to find, takes a screenshot of the specified region of the screen, and then uses OpenCV's `matchTemplate` function to find the image. You can adjust the threshold of `max_val` to make the matching more or less strict.

Adjust the `region` if you want to search only a particular area of the screen. The `region` parameter should be a tuple `(x, y, width, height)`, specifying the top-left corner and the size of the region you want to capture and search within.

Please note that the performance of image matching can vary depending on the resolution and size of the images involved, as well as the region of the screen being captured. If you're experiencing performance issues, you might need to resize the images or use more efficient matching algorithms provided by OpenCV.

Good luck!